# Upgraded from Kubuntu 17.04 to 18.04 and lost much of desktop functionality

Tags: upgrade, graphics, icons, taskbar, desktop-icons

I was given a desktop running Kubuntu 17.04 and asked to install a program. Given the lack of repository support for 17.04, I told them I need to upgrade them to 18.04. I did so, but when I logged in following the reboot, there is a lot missing from the desktop. Not the files, those are all still there. But the taskbar is gone, the application icons are all the sheet of paper. And I keep finding a number of functions missing. I tried to take a screenshot and it gave a window saying `There was an error running mate-screenshot:
Failed to execute child process "mate-screenshot" (no such file or directory)`
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEDCS.jpg)
I'm not really sure what happened, but I'd rather not need to wipe it clean to get a functional desktop back.

Comment: How did you upgrade from 17.04 to 18.04?  Did you re-install? (ie. 'something-else'' but no-format of partitions?) as skipping upgrades is untested & unsupported officially. Any why would `mate-screenshot` be called?  (it's GTK+ based) unlike Kubuntu/KDE's `spectacle` (Qt and default on Kubuntu).  Is it Kubuntu? or Ubuntu-MATE?  (I see mention of `marco` bottom left which is also a MATE-compositor/window-manager & not used by kde/Kubuntu).   If you logout, you may find you can login with KDE instead of using what I suspect is MATE.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades. I upgraded by replacing my sources.list file with what is listed here, then replacing `CODENAME` with `BIONIC`. Have I broken things by skipping Aardvark?

Comment: Also, I pressed `Print Screen` in an attempt to show you what my suddenly bare-bones desktop looked like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first please make sure that you have installed all needed updates for 18.04 LTS with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

if any of last two commands have errors, then check the repository settings in Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`). They should look as shown on screenshots below:

[image: Ubuntu Software]

[image: Updates]

After making changes on these tabs run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` again.

---

If you plan to use MATE DE on this system you can install it by installing *task* package with

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

If you missed only MATE Screenshot then you can install it simply with

```
sudo apt-get install mate-utils
```

Comment: All the repositories and upgrade commands came back fine. I just stumbled on the `Print Screen` button not working as I was trying to take a screenshot to show my newly bare-bones desktop.

Comment: All the repositories were fine, but re-installing MATE desktop seems to have done it. Thank you!